# Extend class with a custom constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, extension-methods

Is it possible to extend an existing class with a custom constructor? I want to parse an ISO8601 `String` to a `Duration` and best thing would be to use it as an extension on `Duration`.

The problem is, if I create an extension method `fromIso8601` on Duration, I need to have an instance of `Duration`. E.g.:

```dart
Duration dur = Duration();
dur.fromIso8601(inputString);
```

As you can see, this is a bad software design. So the better solution would be to have a constructor like:

```dart
Duration dur = Duration.fromIso8601(inputString);
```

Is it possible to extend a class with a new constructor?
Is there ano6ther solution which might be more suitable?

Comment: It is not possible to add constructors (nor `static` methods) to classes via extensions.  I'd just make a freestanding function.

Comment: @Nagual `DateTime.parse` can parse ISO 8601 *dates*, not *durations*, and using `DateTime` to represent durations is a bad idea that would be rather error-prone.

Comment: @jamesdlin Unfortunate, so having a freestanding function seems the second best solution to me, even though I really dislike such functions

Comment: You *can* add static method but then you will need to use the extension class name like: DurationExtension.fromIso8601(...). This is not ideal but better than freestanding function imo.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you think is the Duration in seconds for 'P1M'?

Comment: @jabbson 2592000 seconds

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin but not every month has 30 days, it can also be 31 or 28 days, why 2592000 seconds and not 2678400 or 2419200 seconds?

Comment: Well thats right, haven't thought about that. There is a package called `Jiffy` which can handle such things.
https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy